# На каком уровне правильней всего размещать классы Spring Security (java config)?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

На каком уровне правильней всего размещать конфигурационные классы, бины, фильтры и остальное что будет работать непосредственно с Spring Security (java config)? Раскидывать все по разным уровням или на каком-то одном все размещать (напр. на уровне Configuration)?

Comment: Под "уровнями" вы имеете в виду пакеты?

Comment: @nofate я имею ввиду: `@Configuration, @Service ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@Configuration` и `@Service` - это принципиально разные инструменты.

Отдельные самодостаточные компоненты, которые будут обнаруживаться через `component-scan` и дергаться через `@Autowired` можно помечать аннотацией `@Component`.

`@Service` это по сути синоним `@Component` с более узкой семантикой: этой аннотацией обычно помечают классы, являющиеся сервисными фасадами, т.е. предоставляющие API именно к бизнес логике, а не к инфраструктуре.

И те и другие будут внедряться как `@Autowired`-зависимости независимо от выбранного вами способа конфигурирования Spring-a (xml, java, groovy).

`@Configuration` - это уже способ смотать изолентой ваши классы. Вы можете в явном виде создавать экземпляры нужных бинов, вручную фаршировать их зависимостями и возвращать.

---

**TL;DR**: Бины, которые могут быть обнаружены автоматически помечайте как `@Component`, которые не могут - кладите руками внутри `@Configuration`.